# Check if the following systems are determined: $AX = 0$, $BX = 0$, $A$, $B$ and $X$ are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&1&1\\
0&2&4&4\\
1&3&1&1\\
0&0&-2&0 \end{bmatrix} \\
B = \begin{bmatrix}
2&1&-1\\
1&1&1\\
-1&0&2\\ \end{bmatrix} \\$$

The determinants are also given: $\det(A)=-32$ and $\det(B)=0$. X isn't given.

I know that a way of solving this system is by doing $A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}0 \Leftrightarrow X = 0$. I can do this because A is invertible but I can't do this for B. What I am wondering is, does a matrix have to be invertible for a system to be solvable or does it have to be invertible specifically if the system has to be possible and determined?

Comment: for $B$, $X$ could have columns that are any multiple of $\pmatrix{-2\\3\\-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An answer to your general query.**

As you know, the equation $Ax=b$ is solvable and determined if $A$ is invertible.

If $A$ is singular then:-

the system may be impossible (e.g. put $A=0$ and $b\ne 0)$

the system may be solvable  (e.g. put $b=0$)

it is never possible and determined.